# Day of the week from Timestamp , SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a timestamp column in my table, out of which i want to create a new column - day of week -  (Ex. Monday, Tuesday ) to the table. I'm using PGAdmin4

Comment: PGAdmin4 is just a tool for connecting to the database, it won't make a difference to this question. What might make a difference is what version of Postgres you're using (9.4, 10, 11, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This will get the day of the week, replace GETDATE() with your timestamp.

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE())
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
select to_char(now(), 'Day')
```